# Two forms in one page

Tags: php, forms, symfony, email, twig

Hey guys i have the same form twice in the same page (i tried to read a lot of question with the same problem but that did not resolve my problem ...) my problem is that when i send one form that send the other one too, WITH SAME DATA ...

So there is my controler (the form is sending a mail) :

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Mail');
    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form2->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Demande')
            ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
            ->setFrom($loggedAs->getEmail())
            ->setBody($this->render('mail_templates/probleme.html.twig', array(
                'nom' => $loggedAs->getFirstName(),
                'prenom' => $loggedAs->getSecondName(),
                'content' => $form2["content"]->getData(),
            )), 'text/html');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Rapport envoyé");
    }

    $defaultData2 = array('message2' => 'Mail2');
    $form3 = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData2)
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form3->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form3->isSubmitted() && $form3->isValid()) {

        $message2 = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Signaler un problème')
            ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
            ->setFrom($loggedAs->getEmail())
            ->setBody($this->render('mail_templates/probleme.html.twig', array(
                'nom' => $loggedAs->getFirstName(),
                'prenom' => $loggedAs->getSecondName(),
                'content' => $form3["content"]->getData(),
            )), 'text/html');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message2);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Rapport envoyé");
    }
```

and my html (twig) :

```
{{ form_start(form2) }}
{{ form_widget(form2.content) }}
{% if form_errors(form2.content) %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {{ form_errors(form2.content) | striptags }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Envoyer</button>
{{ form_end(form2) }}
{{ form_start(form3) }}
{{ form_widget(form3.content) }}
{% if form_errors(form2.content) %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
   {{ form_errors(form3.content) | striptags }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Envoyer</button>
{{ form_end(form3) }}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you submitting the form using AJAX? Normal form submission can't submit two forms at once.

Comment: no i am not using ajax

Comment: Then I don't see how this can be happening. Do you actually see both submissions in the Network tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: yes and i have also two alerts

Comment: Could you also post the actual html rendered for each form? which are the names of the inputs?

Comment: you want an capture ? of the page ? (if is that you want edit the post)

Comment: Nope I would like a screenshot of the html code generated (via element inspection or source code)

Comment: done :) hope you will find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as Mihai Aurelian said you need to name the two forms in order to handle them correctly. As you can see from the posted html code, currently you have two forms containing inputs with the exactly same names. That's why it seems that both forms are submitted with exactly the same data. Since you are building your forms inside a controller and not in a separate Form Type class you should have something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;

public function yourAction(Request $request, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory) {

     $defaultData = array('message' => 'Mail');

     $form2 = $formFactory->createNamedBuilder('form2', FormType::class, $defaultData)
         ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
         ->getForm();

     $defaultData2 = array('message2' => 'Mail2');

     $form3 = $formFactory->createNamedBuilder('form3', FormType::class, $defaultData2)
         ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
         ->getForm();

     $form2->handleRequest($request);

     if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
          // handle form2
     }

     $form3->handleRequest($request);

     if ($form3->isSubmitted() && $form3->isValid()) {
          // handle form3
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: I fixed the missing $formFactory service from the action. But you should get FormFactory service through autowiring by type-hinting $formFactory argument in your action, instead of getting it directly from service container using `$this->get('form.factory')`. You should avoid getting services inside a controller this way, prefer autowiring whenever possible.

Comment: i have this error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "createNamedBuilder"

Comment: Edited my answer to fix that

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your forms and handle them separately. 
You can move your form building code in a MailFormType class and create 2 named forms:

```
$form1 = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('form1', MailFormType::class)
    ->getForm();

$form2 = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('form2', MailFormType::class)
    ->getForm();

if ($request->request->has('form1') {
     // handle form1
}

if ($request->request->has('form2') {
     // handle form2
}
```

Comment: i have this error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "createNamedBuilder"

Comment: That's odd. Are you using this exact code in your controller?

Comment: Ok, if you are using the code from the other ansewer, you need to call "createNamedBuilder" like this: $this->get('form.factory') ->createNamedBuilder().